# How to flood fill the frame with a pattern image using imagick php class?

Tags: php, imagick, gmagick

I want to flood fill the frame with tiled image instead of color. Currently im using this codes

```
$imagick = new \Imagick('image.jpg');
$imagick->scaleImage(300, 300, false);

// Create frame placeholder
$imagick->frameimage( 'red','30','30', 30, 0);

// Flood fill with color
$imagick->floodFillPaintImage('green', 10, '#6e0000',0, 0,false
);

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

and the result:

[image]

but i want a result like this

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use this? http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/picframe/index.php

Comment: @EGHM Thanks but im trying to avoid to use the exec function as a bit complicated and hard to edit unlike using the class.

Comment: I think you meant to reply to @ChrisG I just inlined your image link.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Its meant for @ChrisG